# Mutation::Apply error: fanout 'sequential/dense/BiasAdd' exist for missing node 'sequential/dense/MatMul'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, metal

Creating a simple linear regression model to detect miles per gallon from horsepower, for some reason the model simply wont .fit, i can .predict, .summary ect. - this is not the whole code, only the section where the model is created. All the other code is cleaning data

```
# Building horsepower normalizer
horsepower_features = np.array(train_features['Horsepower'])
horsepower_val_features = np.array(val_features['Horsepower'])
horsepower_test = np.array(test_features['Horsepower'])

horsepower_labels = np.array(train_labels)
horsepower_val_labels = np.array(val_labels)
horsepower_test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

horsepower_normalizer = layers.Normalization(input_shape=[1,], axis=None)
horsepower_normalizer.adapt(horsepower_features)

print(horsepower_normalizer.mean.numpy())
print('Dataset not normalized', horsepower_features)
print('Dataset normalized', horsepower_normalizer(horsepower_features).numpy)

horsepower_model = keras.Sequential([
    horsepower_normalizer,
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])
horsepower_model.summary()

print(horsepower_model.predict(horsepower_features[:10]))

horsepower_model.compile(
    loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

history = horsepower_model.fit(
    horsepower_features,
    horsepower_labels,
    epochs=100,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(horsepower_val_features, horsepower_val_labels)
)
```

This is the error it returns

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 normalization_1 (Normaliza  (None, 1)                 3         
 tion)                                                           
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 2         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 5 (24.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 2 (8.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 3 (16.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
2023-09-26 09:39:56.650231: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step
[[ 0.01643855]
 [-0.34483466]
 [-0.45892093]
 [ 0.8720856 ]
 [-0.99132353]
 [-0.07863335]
 [-0.30680588]
 [-0.26877713]
 [-0.17370522]
 [-0.32582027]]
Epoch 1/100
2023-09-26 09:39:56.799326: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2023-09-26 09:39:56.807283: F metal_plugin/src/graph/remapper/remapper.cc:3827] Mutation::Apply error: fanout 'sequential/dense/BiasAdd' exist for missing node 'sequential/dense/MatMul'.

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Ive spend hours trying to fix it, uninstalled, reinstalled anaconda ect and havent been able to fix it. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assumed you are deploying it on macOS tensorflow-metal. If yes, it would be incompatible version between tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal.
eg. On this day the latest tensorflow version is 2.15. The latest tensorflow-metal version is 1.1.0 which is compatible with tensorflow==2.14.0.
In conclusion, you should downgrade your dependencies.

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-metal/
please see more at the Project description.